# When I am trying to make ay array of scores[4] or scores[5], then its stopping looping after 2. Except that it works for any other array

Tags: c

When I am trying to make ay array of scores[4] or scores[5], then its stopping looping after 2. Except that it works for any other array.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    
    int n;
    int scores[n];
    printf("Enter the number of scores you have? ");
    scanf("%i", &n);
    
    printf("%i\n", n);
    
    
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
       printf("Enter the score:\n");
       
       
       scanf("%i", &scores[n]);
       
       
       printf("The number of loop condition is: %i\n", i);
       
    }

    
}
```

Comment: Really, you created an account on stackoverflow but DIDN'T searched `array in C` or `scanf in C` on google.

Comment: What is the value of `n` in these two statements? `int n; int scores[n];` You probably want to read the size before declaring the array with a garbage value as the size.

Answer (score 1):

`int n;` is an *uninitialized* variable, containing an *indeterminate* value.

`int scores[n];` is a variable-length array, defined to have an *indeterminate* amount of elements.

If `n` happens to be less than one, this invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior). If `n` happens to be very large, you risk exhausting stack memory.

If the value later given by `scanf("%i", &n);` is greater than zero but less than the original, indeterminate value of `n`, then `scanf("%i", &scores[n]);` will eventually invoke [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) by reading beyond the end of the array.

---

In a bog standard C program, everything happens in order. You must give `n` a value *before* you use it to construct an array. You must ensure that this value is within an appropriate range.

Additionally, you must check the return value of `scanf` is the expected number of *conversions*.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter the number of scores you have? ");

    if (1 != scanf("%i", &n) || n < 1 || n > 128) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid number of scores.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Number of scores: %i\n", n);

    int scores[n];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       printf("Enter the score (#%i): ", i);

       if (1 != scanf("%i", &scores[n])) {
           fprintf(stderr, "Invalid score.\n");
           return 1;
       }
    }
}
```

```
Enter the number of scores you have? 3
Number of scores: 3
Enter the score (#0): 23
Enter the score (#1): 42
Enter the score (#2): 51
```